# Custom Cell doesn't load correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c

My custom cell doesn't load as I want it to.  I've been changing things around of a long time now, and I know I am just not doing something I'm supposed to be doing.

I didn't do anything besides design the cell, set my constraints on my cell prototype, and assign it the custom class I made for it, which I did not change at all, yet.  I assume that's the issue, is that I'm missing methods in the custom cell class.

Here's my design:

[image: Setup]

Here's what it renders to be:

[image: Actual]

I don't know what's going on, but my image doesn't show up and the text box ignores constraints.  If I'm doing something blatant, or missing something, fill me in?

EDIT: I actually got a crazy long error.  Am I supposed to overload something to keep it from auto-layout-ing or something?

```
2014-07-18 18:23:43.897 MeNext[4703:60b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: 

(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10933fab0 V:[UILabel:0x10933f900(90)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1093411c0 V:|-(0)-[UILabel:0x10933f900]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x10933f820 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x109341260 V:[UILabel:0x10933f900]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x10933f820 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10933a2f0 h=--& v=--& V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x10933f820(91)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10933fab0 V:[UILabel:0x10933f900(90)]>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2014-07-18 18:23:43.900 MeNext[4703:60b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x109317d90 V:[UILabel:0x109317c50(90)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10933c290 V:|-(0)-[UILabel:0x109317c50]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x109332840 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10933c330 V:[UILabel:0x109317c50]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x109332840 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1095685f0 h=--& v=--& V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x109332840(91)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x109317d90 V:[UILabel:0x109317c50(90)]>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2014-07-18 18:23:43.902 MeNext[4703:60b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x109320d30 V:[UILabel:0x109332d50(90)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x109337ad0 V:|-(0)-[UILabel:0x109332d50]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x109332c90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x109337b70 V:[UILabel:0x109332d50]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x109332c90 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x109348490 h=--& v=--& V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x109332c90(91)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x109320d30 V:[UILabel:0x109332d50(90)]>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2014-07-18 18:23:43.904 MeNext[4703:60b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x109340530 V:[UIButton:0x109340340(17)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x109340c60 V:[UIButton:0x109340a20(17)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x109341120 V:|-(20)-[UIButton:0x109340340]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x10933f820 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x109341350 V:[UIButton:0x109340a20]-(20)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x10933f820 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10933a2f0 h=--& v=--& V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x10933f820(91)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1093413a0 V:[UIButton:0x109340340]-(16)-[UIButton:0x109340a20]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x109340c60 V:[UIButton:0x109340a20(17)]>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2014-07-18 18:23:43.905 MeNext[4703:60b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10933b500 V:[UIButton:0x10933b310(17)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10933bd30 V:[UIButton:0x10933baf0(17)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10933c1f0 V:|-(20)-[UIButton:0x10933b310]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x109332840 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10933c420 V:[UIButton:0x10933baf0]-(20)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x109332840 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1095685f0 h=--& v=--& V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x109332840(91)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10933c470 V:[UIButton:0x10933b310]-(16)-[UIButton:0x10933baf0]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10933bd30 V:[UIButton:0x10933baf0(17)]>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2014-07-18 18:23:43.906 MeNext[4703:60b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1093333d0 V:[UIButton:0x109333200(17)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x109336890 V:[UIButton:0x109336670(17)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x109337a30 V:|-(20)-[UIButton:0x109333200]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x109332c90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x109337c60 V:[UIButton:0x109336670]-(20)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x109332c90 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x109348490 h=--& v=--& V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x109332c90(91)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x109337d00 V:[UIButton:0x109333200]-(16)-[UIButton:0x109336670]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x109336890 V:[UIButton:0x109336670(17)]>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

EDIT 2: Here's my CellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"QueueCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = _tracks[indexPath.row][@"title"];
    if(_thumbnails.count == _tracks.count)
    {
        [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_thumbnails[indexPath.row]]];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: can you add your CellAtIndexRow method implementation here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to subclass your UITableViewCell if you want to put a ImageView where you want it, and have your text follow constraints. Create  new class of type UITableViewCell, hook it up in Storyboard, and then use

`CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"QueueCell"];`

This works with Storyboard.

```
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"" forIndexPath:indexPath
```

does not work with Storyboard.

Then, in you cell class, hook up your IBOutlet ImageView, label, etc.

Comment: Changing from the bottom dequeue to the top did not change anything.  But I had to make my own properties for the label and image.  Thank you!